# Stuck in cmd script loop

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I'm using a script that, upon logging in, loads **Remote Desktop Protocol (RDP)** and pushes the user to a **Virtual Desktop Environment (VDI)**, along with their credentials. The script does not allow the next command `'Shutdown /l'` to run until it is finished running.

The problem I'm having is that once in the VDI, RDP tries to load up again. How do I prevent this from happening? Thank you in advanced.

`start /wait \\ph-vda\C$\VDI_Users_RDP\%username%.rdp /multimon /noConsentPrompt`

`Shutdown /l`

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're describing is that the same script is running when the user logs in, even when they log into the VDI. You don't want the script to run in the VDI. If that's right, here's one idea.

```
@echo off
if exist "%userprofile%\in_vdi" goto :eof
type nul >"%userprofile%\in_vdi" 
start /wait \\ph-vda\C$\VDI_Users_RDP\%username%.rdp /multimon /noConsentPrompt
del "%userprofile%\in_vdi"
Shutdown /l
```

Comment: Thank for you the response. My problem is, I need the computer to restart once VDI is terminated, so you never go back to the local machine. Hence the 'shutdown /l'

Comment: Does this not work, then? When launched in the VDI, it would see the marker file and exit. Then when the VDI closes, the marker file is deleted from the original instance of the script and the computer shuts down. I guess it depends on whether the host and VDI have access to the same file system.

Comment: I must be doing something wrong. For some reason, this script doesn't load the VDI.
' @echo off
if exist "%userprofile%" goto :eof
type nul >"%userprofile%" 
start /wait \\ph-vda\C$\VDI_Users_RDP\%username%.rdp /multimon /noConsentPrompt
del "%userprofile%"
Shutdown /l  '

The host and VDI do have access to the same file system, so the variables shouldn't change. Sorry if I'm being confusing. I'm new to cmd. Also, I wasn't really sure how to get the code to format.

Comment: It's because %userprofile% always exists no matter what, so it skips to the end (`goto :eof`). `in_vdi` is a 0-byte file that is created right before starting the VDI, and deleted right after exiting, so if it exists, you are hopefully in the VDI. Otherwise, you're not. In either case, you need the `\in_vdi` part in the three lines. But you can name it (and put it) wherever you want.

Comment: That makes more sense. For some reason, the script is still trying to start again while in VDI, then shuts down. Could this be from having the same username/userprofile in both the client and remote?

Comment: You may need to change the path where the VDI looks for the `in_vdi` file (the `if exist` line). It needs to point to the host file system where the file is.

Comment: Might I need to use the full path to the temp file? I feel this simple problem is turning into a big one.